# leddar sensor connecting process always died

Tags: linux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had compile the Leddar ROS package successfully, after that I running the command `roslaunch leddar leddar.launch` and it will show me :

```
... logging to /home/leddar/.ros/log/04b08b28-fb0f-11e5-8fba-c03fd56476ff/roslaunch-leddar-desktop-29633.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://leddar-desktop:36972/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /leddar/fov: 45.0
 * /leddar/frame: leddar
 * /leddar/range: 50.0
 * /leddar/serial: 
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.16

NODES
  /
    leddar (leddar/leddar)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[leddar-1]: started with pid [29651]
[ INFO] [1459850056.151109908]: Connected to default
[ INFO] [1459850056.165976987]: Reconfiguring...
[ INFO] [1459850056.175064564]: Streaming...
[leddar-1] process has died [pid 29651, exit code -7, cmd /home/leddar/catkin_ws/devel/lib/leddar/leddar __name:=leddar __log:=/home/leddar/.ros/log/04b08b28-fb0f-11e5-8fba-c03fd56476ff/leddar-1.log].
log file: /home/leddar/.ros/log/04b08b28-fb0f-11e5-8fba-c03fd56476ff/leddar-1*.log
[leddar-1] restarting process
process[leddar-1]: started with pid [29697]
[ INFO] [1459850070.122849882]: Connected to default
[ INFO] [1459850070.138432672]: Reconfiguring...
[ INFO] [1459850070.145432446]: Streaming...
[leddar-1] process has died [pid 29697, exit code -7, cmd /home/leddar/catkin_ws/devel/lib/leddar/leddar __name:=leddar __log:=/home/leddar/.ros/log/04b08b28-fb0f-11e5-8fba-c03fd56476ff/leddar-1.log].
log file: /home/leddar/.ros/log/04b08b28-fb0f-11e5-8fba-c03fd56476ff/leddar-1*.log
```

the leddar ros package I was git clone from : https://github.com/mcgill-robotics/ros-leddar

anyone know how to solve it?
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231044/leddar-sensor-connecting-process-always-died/) by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2016-04-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-04-05**:
I'm guessing, this is pretty much [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/230868/failed-to-connect-to-serial-with-code-1/)...

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-04-05**:
that problem I just simply use
`roslaunch leddar leddar.launch`
instead of github provide one. Then the problem was solved. now is that I can connect the leddar eva kit but just a while it will died then reconnect back again, repeating the problem until totally failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I had the same problem. I think that my Leddar was configured so that its measurement rate was max. Maybe too many data sent caused troubles... So, I changed 'Accumulation' and 'Oversampling' in order to decrease the measurement rate (see user guide of Leddar Evaluation Kit p28) and it fixed it.
To change the configuration, I modified src/leddar/src/leddar.cpp :
Search for LeddarSetProperty(Handler, PID_ACCUMULATION_EXPONENT, 0, config.accumulations);
and LeddarSetProperty(Handler, PID_OVERSAMPLING_EXPONENT, 0, config.oversampling);
I changed config.accumulations by 7 and config.oversampling by 3 so that measurement rate becomes 12.5 Hz.
I am looking for a smarter way to configure my Leddar, but it's working for now.

---

Originally posted by [MARAUDER](https://answers.ros.org/users/26322/marauder/) with karma: 36 on 2016-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-05-23**:
ok,I will try it when I back to my school. Thank you so much.